# PHP using regex to loop and query mysql to output an excel file

Tags: php, mysql, regex

What am I doing wrong here. I want the array we get at first to be transposed. Then the regex breakups one of the columns so we can query another table in the database to replace that column header with the correct header. Is the Regex correct? Is the transpose correct?

This will get the query we want

```
exportMysqlToCsv($tablename,$tokenmain, $id);
function exportMysqlToCsv($tablename,$tokenmain, $id, $filename = 'Results.csv'){
      $sql_query = "select * from $tablename where $tokenmain";

// Gets the data from the database

$result = mysql_query($sql_query);


$f = fopen('php://temp', 'wt');
$first = true;

$temp = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

I hope this transposes the array we just got . Not sure here

```
array_unshift($temp, null);
$transposed_array = call_user_func_array('array_map', $temp);
```

Then we loop through transposed-array an replace the column header we receive (ex. 111X2222X3333) and split these up to query the headers we want to replace them with and output it to the excel file. This is where I am very confused.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
if ($transposed_array[$i][0])//starts with a number
{
    $sid = regexp /^[0-9]*/

    $gid = regexp /X[0-9]*X/
    //remove first and last character from $gid
    $gid = str_replace("X", "", $gid)

    $qid = regexp /[0-9]*$/

    $question_text = mysql_query("select question from lime_questions where sid =           ".$sid." and gid = ".$gid." and qid = ".$qid." limit 1");
    $transposed_array[$i][5] = $question_test
}
```

This should output the array to the csv file

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
         if ($first)
     {
            fputcsv($f, array_keys($row));
            $first = false;
     }
fputcsv($f, $row);

} // end while
```

//resume normal processing

```
$size = ftell($f);
rewind($f);
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Length: $size");
```

// Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)

```
header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");

fpassthru($f);

exit;
```

Comment: Why are you complicating thing here ??? there is nothing like ` $sid = regexp /^[0-9]*/` or ` $gid = regexp /X[0-9]*X/` can you say what you want to achieve in this loop `for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {` then we can help

Comment: I want this loop to split up the column headers we recieve from the first array. An example of a column header is 111X222X3333. I want to split them up using regex so each one is its own attribute like sid =111 gid=222 and qid=3333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want to achieve because the folloing are not valid PHP expressions

```
  $sid = regexp /^[0-9]*/
  $gid = regexp /X[0-9]*X/
  $qid = regexp /[0-9]*$/
```

But form your comments

> I want this loop to split up the column headers we recieve from the first array. An example of a column header is 111X222X3333. I want to split them up using regex so each one is its own attribute like sid =111 gid=222 and qid=3333

All you need is

```
$string = "111X222X3333" ;
list($sid,$gid,$qid) = explode("X", $string);
```

Comment: however there 100s of strings like 111X2222X3333 so I would want a loop to explode all of these that it finds in the header. one way I was thinking of doing it would be a loop whenever it finds a header that starts with an int

Comment: just put this line `list($sid,$gid,$qid) = explode("X", $string);` in your loop .. only replace `$string` to actual value you are spliting