# PHP loop to explode an array of values and loop to query newly exploded values

Tags: php, mysql

So I am attempting to loop through and print these values to an excel file. I was able to figure that out but am now attempting to add code to be able to explode the original values I was getting.

```
$col = 1; 
while($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$row = 1;
if ($col == 1) {
    $row_headings = array_keys($row_data);
    foreach($row_headings as $value) {
```

Everything works until here. The values we get come out as 111X222X333 so I want to explode them and then query a new array of values

```
        list($sid,$gid,$qid) = explode("X", $value)
    $results="select * from lime questions where sid =".$sid." and gid =".$gid." and qid".$qid;
    }
foreach(mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
```

these were the 3 lines I added to an already working loop. I am wondering what I am doing wrong here.

```
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $results);
        $row++;
    }
    }
    $row = 1;
    $col++;
}
foreach($row_data as $value) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
    $row++;
}
$col++;
```

}

Where am I messing up the loops

Comment: This looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242321/php-explode-function-loop-to-be-used-on-column-headers-to-return-desired-values and even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166492/php-using-regex-to-loop-and-query-mysql-to-output-an-excel-file to me...

Comment: it is very similar. however worded differently in an attempt to find a solution. I felt that some may not have understood what I was asking for and wanted to make it as clear as possible. This is, in my opinion, the most clear version of what I am asking for

Comment: Second code section has few errors: 1) missing `;` at the end of first line, 2) table name in mysql query has space in it (should it be `lime_questions`?), 3) missing `=` in mysql query at `qid`. There seems to be too many closing braces at third code section.